# How should API treat POST request, with body that has wrong FK Id?

Tags: rest, validation, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

What should Web API return from the `POST` request that Body contains wrong reference (FK Id)?

For example this request: `POST /api/addresses/`, with body:

```
{
  "street": "Foo Street",
  "city": "Bar"
  "userId": 333,
}
```

I have 2 very simple questions:

1. What status code should I return if there is no user 333 in the database? `400` or `404`?
2. Should I call DB and verify if User 333 exists before Insert or let DB fail and return *"FK exception"*?

**BTW**. Just to clarify: If the id is used in the URL, I'm returning 404. But that's for `GET` requests, like `api/users/333`. Here, I'm asking about `POST` (or `PUT`) requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass back `400 Bad Request` as the request does not have the correct information to complete the request. Allow the database to fail, handle the exceptions in the way your system requires, and return the code.

To handle the case of whether a valid `userid`, make sure the caller is aware of the user IDs before calling. The client could make a `GET` request to `/api/users/` to get a valid list of users before submitting the `POST` request to `/api/addresses/`, or an invididual `userid` could have been passed back during a previously ran process, such as logging in.

Comment: what about wrong id in the URL and GET request? For example: `GET /api/users/333/addresses`? Should I check if user 333 exists first? Should I return 400 or 404 if it doesn't?

Comment: If you're doing a GET, that's the point you're trying to either get a valid user or not. If the user ```333``` doesn't exist, then return ```404 Not Found```. Maybe include a body to state ```user 333 could not be found``` to differentiate from a ```404 Endpoint not found```